# Looking for a solution to speed up `pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas` processing on a large dataset

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, pyspark, bigdata

I'm working with a dataset stored in S3 bucket (parquet files) consisting of a total of `~165 million` records (with ~30 columns). Now, the requirement is to first `groupby` a certain ID column then generate `250+ features` for each of these grouped records based on the data. Building these features is quite complex using multiple Pandas functionality along with 10+ supporting functions. The groupby function should generate `~5-6 million records`, hence the final output should be `6M x 250` shaped dataframe.

Now, I've tested the code on a smaller sample and it works fine. The issue is, when I'm implementing it on the entire dataset, it takes a very long time - the progress bar in Spark display doesn't change even after 4+ hours of running. I'm running this in AWS EMR Notebook connected to a Cluster (1 m5.xlarge Master & 2 m5.xlarge Core Nodes).
I've tried with `1 m5.4xlarge Master & 2 m5.4xlarge Core Nodes`, `1 m5.xlarge Master & 8 m5.xlarge Core Nodes` combinations among others. None of them have shown any progress.
I've tried running it in Pandas in-memory in my local machine for ~650k records, the progress was ~3.5 iterations/sec which came to be an ETA of `~647 hours`.

So, the question is - can anyone share any better solution to reduce the time consumption and speed up the processing ? Should another cluster type be used for this use-case ? Should this be refactored or should Pandas dataframe usage be removed or any other pointer would be really helpful.

Thanks much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First things first: is your data partitioned enough to take advantage of all of your workers? If some part of your process causes it to coalesce to e.g. a single partition, then you're basically running single-threaded.

Beyond that, I don't know for certain without seeing the code, but here's a subtle behaviour that can cause runtimes to become massive:

```
source_df = # some pandas dataframe with a lot of features in columns

flattened_df = your_df.stack().reset_index().unstack() # Turn the features into rows

spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(flattened_df) # 'index' is the column that contains the feature name

# a function to do a linear regression and calculate residual
def your_good_pandas_function(key, slice):
  clf = LinearRegression()
  X = slice[subset,of,columns]
  y = slice[key]
  clf.train(X,y)
  predicted = clf.predict(X)
  return y-predicted

def your_bad_pandas_function(key, slice):
  clf = LinearRegression()
  X = slice[subset,of,columns]
  y = slice[key]
  clf.train(X,y)
  predicted = clf.predict(X)
  return source_df[key]-predicted

spark_df.groupBy('index').applyInPandas(your_good_pandas_function,schema=some_schema) #fast
spark_df.groupBy('index').applyInPandas(your_bad_pandas_function,schema=some_schema) #slow
```

These two ApplyInPandas functions do the same thing - they linear-regress some characteristics against a feature and calculate the residual. The first uses variables that are in scope within the pandas UDF. The second uses a variable that is out of scope of the pandas UDF. In the second case, Spark will help you out by broadcasting `source_df` to every single invocation of your pandas UDF. This will cause enormous memory usage and definitely kill your job.

Your data don't seem large enough to take that long, so my guess is that the reason why it works on a small subset and not the larger set *may* be because you're inadvertently broadcasting the larger set to your `applyInPandas` function calls.